FFmpeg -itsoffset causes visual artifacts and time jumps in WMP and Movies & TV
I'm encountering visual artifacts (screen corruption) and unexpected time jumps when playing a video file generated by FFmpeg in Windows Media Player and Microsoft Movies & TV. The same video plays correctly in PotPlayer, MPV, and VLC.
The command I used to delay the audio by 5 seconds was:
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i video.mp4 -itsoffset 5 -i video.mp4 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy out.mp4

The output video works as expected in most modern players but exhibits visual corruption and automatically skips to the 00:05 timestamp in Microsoft's players.
I tried removing the -c copy option from the command, or changing the output format to mkv, but neither solved the problem. This is not a problem with the encoding, but with the player's support for MPEG-4 edit list tables.
I aim to produce a video with FFmpeg that will play without issues on any player, including very old ones. Is there a way to tweak FFmpeg parameters or use alternative strategies to ensure the output video is universally compatible across all media players?

Since MS players don't support editlists, you'll have to pad the audio to achieve the offset in a compatible manner.
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -itsoffset 5 -i video.mp4 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0 -y out.mp4
